# How Can I stop ParentNode from getting called recursively everytime I trigger the event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this check button to remove elements from the list, and whenever I press an element from the bottom of the lists it removes the whole thing, I've tried using break but it keeps executing.

This is what the code looks like:

```
let checkBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-round');
      for (let i = 0; i < checkBtns.length; i++) {
        checkBtns[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log(`executing for ${i}`);
          checkBtns[i].parentNode.remove();
          tasks.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        });
      }
```

And here's a screenshot of the behavior in console:

[image]

- The underlined log is the normal expected behavior when I delete a node that's on top of the list
- The log under is for when I delete a node on the bottom that recursively calls itself

Comment: I think you should use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName` since the latter holds live nodes so it gets updated when you remove the nodes referenced by it and hence their indexes are also updated. Also, you don't need that break keyword.

Answer (score 0):

As @aerial mentioned replacing getElementsByClassName with querySelectorAll solved the issue